# Drawing lots of overlapping 2D shadows

Tags: c++, geometry, shadow

I'm working on a program that involves drawing lots of very simple overlapping shadows.  There's nothing fancy about the shadows: they have hard edges and there is a single light source at infinity (i.e. all shadows are parallel).  The unique aspect is that the shadows represent areas of *partially* absorbed light, and so many many shadows can overlap to make progressively darker regions.

Here is an image to illustrate the idea:

[image: 2D overlapping shadows]

My question is this: *What would be a good way to take the shadows in my program (stored as convex quadrilaterals) and efficiently draw them to the screen?*

I can simply draw them all with the appropriate alpha values and the result looks fine, but doing so can get awfully slow.  I think this is because pixels that are in many shadows are drawn over many times.  I suspect an approach that only draws to each pixel once could be much faster.

My program is in C++ and I'm using Qt to do the UI and drawing.  I'd be happy to make use of a library to do polygon clipping or something (e.g. [Clipper](http://www.angusj.com/delphi/clipper.php) or boost), but I'd be reluctant to dive into the world of OpenGL/GPUs (unless there is a particularly painless way of doing so).

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I think an efficcient way to draw your shadow will be to do something like ray-tracing. It means basically that you iter through every pixel in your image and draw in the right color by checking how many "wall" the reversed ray traverses. something like :

```
For every pixel in the image
    compute the reversed lightray (from the pixel to your light direction)
    compute the number of walls traversed by your lightray
    (= nb of intersections with all the segments/walls)
    draw the pixel according to the number of intersections 
    (the more intersections, the darker)
```

It should be easy and O(n) in complexity with the number of pixels ^^

By the way I think boost::geometry can manage intersections.

Comment: Ah, thank you!  It all seems so much simpler now to think of it in terms of pixels, not in terms of shadow polygons.  I'll try implementing this, and I suspect the performance will go up considerably.  If it is fast enough, I might even try supersampling the pixels for a bit of anti-aliasing.

Comment: @rrwick: You're welcome. Good luck with the code. Share the result if possible.